# OO Approach python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to learn more about OO in python, but I don't quite understand why is my mistake:

This (functional approach works as expected)

```
def code_func(text, a, b):
        l1 = a + b
        l2 = b + a
        tabela = dict((l1[x],l2[x]) for x in range(len(l1)))
        textb = ""
        for i in range(len(text)):
            textb +=  text[i] if str(text[i]) not in tabela else tabela[str(text[i])]
        return textb
```

However this approach below doesn't:
note-> I know that its counter productive to have a method just to call another one, but I am trying this just to understand better OO concepts.
It does split the text into lines and the result is not the same as the former.

```
class Cipher:
    def __init__(self, l1, l2, text):
        self.l1 = l1
        self.l2 = l2
        self.text = text


    def code(self):

        l1 = self.l1 + self.l2
        l2 = self.l2 + self.l1
        tabela = dict((l1[x],l2[x]) for x in range(len(l1)))
        textb = ""
        for i in range(len(self.text)):
            textb +=  self.text[i] if str(self.text[i]) not in tabela else \
            tabela[str(self.text[i])]
        return textb   


    def encode(self):
        return self.code()
```

Samples of outputs in inputs to show what's happening:

input: `code_func("criptografia","zenitpolar","polarzenit")`

Output: `"ctazregtifai"`

---

OOP:

input:

```
crypto = Chiper("criptografia", "zenitpolar", "polarzenit") 
crypto.encode()
```

output:

```
"c  
aerng  
tfat"
```

Comment: In which way it doesn't work?

Comment: "doesn't work" is **never** a good way to describe a problem. Please describe what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: Reading it fast, it looks ok, but without a proper error description we can't do anything. Traceback, unexpected output, whatever...

Comment: I edited to show examples of input/output

Comment: You're asking about object orientation and not about your code, but this functionality is provided in the stdlib: `string.translate(text, string.maketrans(a+b,b+a))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first approach you are passing arguments

```
code_func("criptografia","zenitpolar","polarzenit")
```

as per your function definition:

```
def code_func(text, a, b):

#text = "criptografia"
#a = "zenitpolar"
#b = "polarzenit"
```

whereas in your second approach, you are passing the arguments in the same order:

```
crypto = Chiper("criptografia", "zenitpolar", "polarzenit")
```

but the `__init__` function takes arguments in a different order:

```
def __init__(self, l1, l2, text):

#l1 = "criptografia"
#l2 = "zenitpolar"
#text = "polarzenit"
```

that's why the outputs are different. Call your function like this:

```
crypto = Chiper("zenitpolar", "polarzenit", "criptografia")
```